# Como capturar som do microfone do dispositivo

Tags: java, android

Como capturar o som do microfone do dispositivo. Especificando melhor. Eu preciso apenas do volume do som capturado.
A ideia é chamar um método à um determinado volume.É possível?

Comment: Veja [isto](http://androidexample.com/Detect_Noise_Or_Blow_Sound_-_Set_Sound_Frequency_Thersold/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=108&aaid=130)

Comment: E aí Emerson como vai? Passando por aqui me deparei com sua questão. Acredito que pelo tempo você já deve ter conseguindo resolver. Todavia, acredito que para a ocasião da pergunta, este link poderia ajudar: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html
quanto ao volume, aqui:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777060/android-sample-microphone-without-recording-to-get-live-amplitude-level De qualquer forma, ficarei feliz em saber que você já resolveu. Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado @Bruno Anjos